# ssh tunnel/forwarding & iptables

Tags: iptables

I am trying to setup iptables + tunnel via ssh and just can't succeed with this.

I am trying to setup a tunnel:

```
ssh -N -f -L 8500:localhost:8500 root@<ip-of-the-server>
```

And the connection is dropped due to last row:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

Question: what should I include in iptables to allow such a tunneling from specific IP ie my computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
iptables -A INPUT --src 127.0.0.1 --protocol tcp --dport 8500 -J ACCEPT
```

for the tunneld port. This allows connections from 127.0.0.1 to port 8500/tcp

```
iptables -A INPUT --src $IP_Here --protocol tcp --dport 22 -J ACCEPT
```

For the ssh-connection (This would allow connections on port 22, which is ssh from $IP_Here, which you have to set/replace with a actual IP Address)

Comment: The -J parameter should be -j (lowercase). It may work but the documentation only mentions lowercase.