# How to create SSH reverse tunnel with iptables forwarding?

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables, ssh-tunneling

I have a server in my home network (cannot port forward) and a VPS on the WAN. I need requests on a certain port, **to**, not from, the VPS to be forwarded to my home server. I have an SSH tunnel which works fine if I send the request to `localhost` on VPS. However I want requests forwarded to VPS's `localhost` from internet be sent to my home server through the tunnel. And it needs to be bi-directional.

I have seen [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437548/ssh-tunnel-forwarding-iptables) question, however it doesn't work for me. It is quite possible that I did something incorrectly.

My exact procedure:
On server `a`, my home server, I ran this command to set up the tunnel:

```
ssh -v -N -R 2222:localhost:22 root@server-b.com
```

I ran the following command on server `b` (VPS):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2223 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:2222
```

And tried to `ssh` from another machine:

```
ssh root@server-b.com -p 2223
```

I set `GatewayPorts yes` in `sshd_config` however I am still finding the same problem:
***ssh: connect to host server-b.com port 2223: Connection refused***.

Comment: It would be useful documenting in your own post exactly what was done

Comment: You might want to look at the `GatewayPorts` setting on the VPS server `sshd_config`.  This can allow the remote port 2222 to bind to all IP addresses and so be visible without NATting.

Comment: @StephenHarris I'll check that out. Thanks

Comment: @StephenHarris sorry for the inactivity but it didn't work. I set `GatewayPorts` to `yes` however it is still not functioning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `GatewayPorts yes` and `AllowTcpForwarding yes` in `sshd_config` on server `b`. With `GatewayPorts clientspecified` explicitly mention IP `0.0.0.0` or `*` on server `a` to create reverse tunnel. So that sshd on server `b` accepts connections from public too:

```
ssh -NTR *:2222:localhost:22 root@server-b.com
```

Otherwise sshd listens on loopback interface only as is the case with `GatewayPorts no`.

Now `ssh` from another machine to port `2222`:

```
ssh root@server-b.com -p 2222
```

You'll be logged in to server `a` after authentication.
No need to set up `iptables` forwarding. Btw, avoid user `root` for remote logins, if possible.

---

If you don't want to set `GatewayPorts` option, then you need to forward traffic from some other port, say `2223`, to `localhost:2222`.

- This can be done with `iptables` on server `b`:

  ```
  iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2223 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:2222
  ```

  <sup>* `REDIRECT` works only for same interface</sup>

  But [routing to `loopback` interface](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/163683/) isn't allowed unless:

  ```
  echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/route_localnet
  ```

  Now `ssh` from another machine to port `2223`:

  ```
  ssh root@server-b.com -p 2223
  ```

Another option is to setup some minimal local forwarding server from port `2223` to `2222` using tools like `ssh`, `socat`, `netcat`, `*inetd` etc.

- On server `b`, with `socat`:

  ```
  socat TCP-LISTEN:2223,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:2222
  ```
- Or with `netcat`:

  ```
  nc -l -p 2223 -c "nc 127.0.0.1 2222"
  ```
- Or with `ssh`:

  ```
  ssh -4gfNTL 2223:localhost:2222 localhost
  ```

Any of the above can be combined with reverse tunnel to do a *double forwarding* from server `a` in a single step:

```
ssh -TR *:2222:localhost:22 root@server-b.com "ssh -4gfNTL 2223:localhost:2222 localhost"
```

Comment: Thanks, I shall try this soon. About root, I've just been too lazy to make a normal user account. Probably should do that soon.

Comment: OH MY GOD IT WORKS! I cannot thank you enough. I've been searching for this for months and it is everything I need. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. I have extended the answer to include other possible options, including `iptables` if you want to go for that.